# Cloudera spark, RDD is empty

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hive

I am trying to create a data frame using pyspark and hive on a cloudera vm,but every time i get this error.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/cloudera/Desktop/TwitterSentimentAnalysis/SentimentAnalysis.py", line 98, in 
    .reduceByKey(lambda a, b: a+b) \
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/context.py", line 62, in toDF
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/context.py", line 404, in createDataFrame
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/context.py", line 285, in _createFromRDD
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/context.py", line 229, in _inferSchema
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 1320, in first
ValueError: RDD is empty

INFO spark.SparkContext: Invoking stop() from shutdown hook

What should I do to fix this error.

Edit 2 - 
    sc = SparkContext(appName="PythonSentimentAnalysis")
    sqlCtx = HiveContext(sc)

```
filenameAFINN = "/home/cloudera/Desktop/TwitterSentimentAnalysis/AFINN/AFINN-111.txt"

 afinn = dict(map(lambda (w, s): (w, int(s)), [ ws.strip().split('\t') for ws in open(filenameAFINN) ]))

filenameCandidate = "file:///home/cloudera/Desktop/TwitterSentimentAnalysis/Candidates/Candidate Mapping.txt"

candidates = sc.textFile(filenameCandidate).map(lambda x: (x.strip().split(",")[0],x.strip().split(","))) \
                   .flatMapValues(lambda x:x).map(lambda y: (y[1],y[0])).distinct()


pattern_split = re.compile(r"\W+")

tweets = sqlCtx.sql("select id, text, entities.user_mentions.name from incremental_tweets")

def sentiment(text):
  words = pattern_split.split(text.lower())
  sentiments = map(lambda word: afinn.get(word, 0), words)
  if sentiments:
   sentiment = float(sum(sentiments))/math.sqrt(len(sentiments))
  else:
   sentiment = 0
   return sentiment

   sentimentTuple = tweets.rdd.map(lambda r: [r.id, r.text, r.name]) \
           .map(lambda r: [sentiment(r[1]),r[2]]) \
           .flatMapValues(lambda x: x) \
           .map(lambda y: (y[1],y[0])) \
           .reduceByKey(lambda x, y: x+y) \
           .sortByKey(ascending=True)

  scoreDF = sentimentTuple.join(candidates) \
        .map(lambda (x,y): (y[1],y[0])) \
        .reduceByKey(lambda a,b: a+b) \
        .toDF()

   scoreRenameDF =  scoreDF.withColumnRenamed("_1","Candidate").withColumnRenamed("_2","Score")

   sqlCtx.registerDataFrameAsTable(scoreRenameDF, "SCORE_TEMP")

   sqlCtx.sql("INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE candidate_score SELECT Candidate, Score FROM SCORE_TEMP")
```

Comment: Could you please share the code snippet also?

Comment: Question updated with code snippet.

Comment: A bit difficult to help without some [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)... Anyhow, is your join with `candidates` giving back any results? Could you post how they look like?
 Cheers.

Comment: I have added the whole code but I don't know where to check for join with candidates data.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check the intermediate RDDs by using below code, if they are created properly:

```
for i in rdd.take(10):   print(i)
```

This will show first 10 entries of your RDD